# Port problem in web application in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

My problem i sthat i have created a web application in visual studio 2008 professional edition but when i run it i have to change the specified port every time otherwise it is not woking properly i have also tried to use the assign automatic port option but the result is same. How can i make the setting to use the visual studio internal server without changing the port number every time.

Comment: "not woking properly" - what exactly isn't working? What is the issue you are seeing?

Comment: for example i have a login page when i launch the web project through visual studio without changing the port number and click on the login button after providing valid userid and password nothing happens just a postback occured on the other hand when i change port number and relaunch the web application the login button on login page let me enter the application content pages after validating userid password correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the port the Visual Studio server uses in the Web tab of the project properties screen:
[alt text http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/fixedcassiniportvs2008.png](http://philippursglove.com/stackoverflow/fixedcassiniportvs2008.png)

Alternatively, if you have it installed, you could change the project to use the local IIS server, which would mean you could use a path like http://localhost/MyProject/default.aspx to get to your project - no knowledge required of what port it's running on.

Comment: I am using the exact setting you have displayed in the figure above but even after selecting the specific port option i have to change the specific port number before launching the web application project with visual studio otherwise the above mentioned problem occurs.